# DataTable update() inserts duplicate new rows without checking if it exists

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, datagridview

I'm trying to use the update() method, but it is inserting my datatable data into my database without checking if the row exists, so it is inserting duplicate data.  It is also not deleting rows that don't exist in datatable.  How to resolve this?  I want to synchronize my datatable with server table.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MyDatabaseDataSet11.Vendor_GUI_Test_Data' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.vendor_GUI_Test_DataTableAdapter.Fill(this.MyDatabaseDataSet11.Vendor_GUI_Test_Data);

    // read target table on SQL Server and store in a tabledata var
    this.ServerDataTable = this.MyDatabaseDataSet11.Vendor_GUI_Test_Data;
}
```

Insertion

```
private void convertGUIToTableFormat()
{
    ServerDataTable.Rows.Clear();

    // loop through GUIDataTable rows
    for (int i = 0; i < GUIDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        String guiKEY = (String)GUIDataTable.Rows[i][0] + "," + (String)GUIDataTable.Rows[i][8] + "," + (String)GUIDataTable.Rows[i][9];
        //Console.WriteLine("guiKey: " + guiKEY);

        // loop through every DOW value, make a new row for every true
        for(int d = 1; d < 8; d++)
        {
            if ((bool)GUIDataTable.Rows[i][d] == true)
            {
                DataRow toInsert = ServerDataTable.NewRow();
                toInsert[0] = GUIDataTable.Rows[i][0];
                toInsert[1] = d + "";
                toInsert[2] = GUIDataTable.Rows[i][8];
                toInsert[3] = GUIDataTable.Rows[i][9];

                ServerDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(toInsert, 0);
                //printDataRow(toInsert);
                //Console.WriteLine("---------------");
            }
        }
    }
```

Trying to update

```
// I got this adapter from datagridview, casting my datatable to their format
CSharpFirstGUIWinForms.MyDatabaseDataSet1.Vendor_GUI_Test_DataDataTable DT = (CSharpFirstGUIWinForms.MyDatabaseDataSet1.Vendor_GUI_Test_DataDataTable)ServerDataTable;

DT.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { DT.Columns["Vendor"], DT.Columns["DOW"], DT.Columns["LeadTime"], DT.Columns["DemandPeriod"] };

this.vendor_GUI_Test_DataTableAdapter.Update(DT);
```

Comment: Where is your code to fill the datatable?

Comment: Update only does an update instead of an insert if you have already loaded the row from the database. Otherwise it doesn't know it exists.

Comment: @DaleK what do you mean by loaded the row from database can you elaborate?

Comment: Exactly that, you load data from the database using the `Fill()` method and a `select` statement. You modify that data including adding new rows and update it back. If you are creating all your data in the front end, which might duplicate existing data, then your adaptor doesn't know that because you haven't loaded any data, so it assumes it is all new.

Comment: So I should make my own adapter instead of using the datagridview's adapter? They filled it for me but I cant edit the datatable so I made a copy.  See first code.

Comment: @DaleK technically that's not strictly true - Update() performs an UPDATE if the data row's state is Modified, which is little to do with its provenance

Comment: *so I made a copy* -  that's another variable hat points to the same thing. It's not a copy and anything you do to that you could do to the original

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at what happens in the code posted.
First this line:

```
 this.ServerDataTable = this.MyDatabaseDataSet11.Vendor_GUI_Test_Data;
```

This is not a copy, but just an assignment between two variables. The assigned one (ServerDataTable) receives the 'reference' to the memory area where the data coming from the database has been stored. So these two variables 'point' to the same memory area. Whatever you do with one affects what the other sees.

Now look at this line:

```
ServerDataTable.Rows.Clear();
```

Uh! Why? You are clearing the memory area where the data loaded from the database were. Now the Datatable is empty and no records (DataRow) are present there.
Let's look at what happen inside the loop

```
DataRow toInsert = ServerDataTable.NewRow();
```

A new DataRow has been created, now every DataRow has a property called [RowState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.rowstate?view=net-5.0) and when you create a new row this property has the default value of `DataRowState.Detached`, but when you add the row inside the DataRow collection with

```
ServerDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(toInsert, 0);
```

then the `DataRow.RowState` property becomes `DataRowState.Added`.

At this point the missing information is how a TableAdapter behaves when you call `Update`. The adapter needs to build the appropriate INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE sql command to update the database. And what is the information used to choose the proper sql command? Indeed, it looks at the `RowState` property and it sees that all your rows are in the Added state. So it chooses the INSERT command for your table and barring any duplicate key violation you will end in your table with duplicate records.

What should you do to resolve the problem? Well the first thing is to remove the line that clears the memory from the data loaded, then, instead of calling always `InsertAt` you should first look if you have already the row in memory. You could do this using the [DataTable.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select) method. This method requires a string like it is a WHERE statement and you should use some value for the primarykey of your table

```
var rows =  ServerDataTable.Select("PrimaryKeyFieldName = " + valueToSearchFor);
```

if you get a rows count bigger than zero then you can use the first row returned and update the existing values with your changes, if there is no row matching the condition then you can use the InsertAt like you are doing it now.

Comment: Please don't call them DataTableAdapters.. There are DataTables, DataAdapters and TableAdapters. Throwing another name (of something that isn't a thing) in there is really going to cause confusion! 

Comment: @Steve thanks for the pointers.  The reason I tried to use clear is because I'm trying to get rid of any old rows in the datatable that didn't match my insert i.e. only what I'm trying to insert should be in the datatable.  Is there a good way to delete old rows?

Comment: Then you need to perform a direct SQL Command against the table before executing the Update. There is a TRUNCATE TABLE <tablename> command.

Comment: I disagree with "need" there Steve.. there's no "need" to issue a raw truncate. If you want to delete rows from a db that have been downloaded to a dt, you simply `foreach(var r in dt)r.Delete();` to mark he row as deleted and then tableadapter Update to commit the deletes.. no "need" to issue raw sql at all, though you might want to use direct server interaction to dump thousands of rows rather than downloading them to the client.. but even then you'd probably add a custom command to the tableadapter (right click in dataset, add query, query that deletes rows, `delete from table` For example)

Comment: Other thing I wanted to note, in your Select (which I don't disagree with, is useful for generally selecting rows on a generic dt) you'd either, if it's the PK column, use the dedicated Find (FindByxxx in a strongly typed table) or you'd perhaps use LINQ these days (especially in a strongly typed, as there is no casting needed)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying too hard, I think, and you're unfortunately getting nearly everything wrong

```
// read target table on SQL Server and store in a tabledata var
this.ServerDataTable = this.MyDatabaseDataSet11.Vendor_GUI_Test_Data;
```

No, this line of code doesn't do anything at all with the database, it just assigns an existing datatable to a property called ServerDataTable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < GUIDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
```

It isn't clear if GUIDataTable is strongly or weakly typed, but if it's strong (I.e. it lives in your dataset, or is of a type that is a part of your dataset) you will do yourself massive favors if you do *not* access it's Rows collection at all. The way to access a strongly typed datatable is as if it were an array

```
myStronglyTypedTable[2] //yes, third row

myStronglyTypedTable.Rows[2] //no, do not do this- you end up with a base type DataRow that is massively harder to work with
```

Then we have..

```
DataRow toInsert = ServerDataTable.NewRow();
```

Again, don't do this.. you're working with strongly typed datatables. This makes your life easy:

```
var r = MyDatabaseDataSet11.Vendor_GUI_Test_Data.NewVendor_GUI_Test_DataRow();
```

Because now you can refer to everything by name and type, not numerical index and object:

```
r.Total = r.Quantity * r.Price; //yes

toInsert["Ttoal"] = (int)toInsert["Quantity"] * (double)toInsert["Price"]; //no. Messy, hard work, "stringly" typed, casting galore, no intellisense.. The typo was deliberate btw
```

You can also easily add data to a typed datatable like:

```
MyPersonDatatable.AddPersonRow("John, "smith", 29, "New York");
```

Next up..

```
// I got this adapter from datagridview, casting my datatable to their format
    CSharpFirstGUIWinForms.MyDatabaseDataSet1.Vendor_GUI_Test_DataDataTable DT = (CSharpFirstGUIWinForms.MyDatabaseDataSet1.Vendor_GUI_Test_DataDataTable)ServerDataTable;

DT.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { DT.Columns["Vendor"], DT.Columns["DOW"], DT.Columns["LeadTime"], DT.Columns["DemandPeriod"] };

this.vendor_GUI_Test_DataTableAdapter.Update(DT);
```

Need to straighten out the concepts and terminology in your mind here.. that is not an adapter, it didn't come from a datagridview, grid views never provide adapters, your datatable variable was always their format and if you typed it as `DataTable ServerDataTable` then that just makes it massively harder to work with, in the same way that saying `object o = new Person()` - now you have to cast o every time you want to do nearly anything Person specific with it. You could always declare all your variables in every program, as type object.. but you don't.. Hence don't do the equivalent by putting your strongly typed datatables inside DataTable typed variables because you're just hiding away the very things that make them useful and easy to work with

---

If you download rows from a database into a datatable, and you want to...

... delete them from the db, then call Delete on them in the datatable

... update them in the db, then set new values on the existing rows in the datatable

... insert more rows into the db alongside the existing rows, then add more rows to the datatable

Datatables track what you do to their rows. If you clear a datatable it doesn't mark every row as deleted, it just jettisons the rows. No db side rows will be affected. If you delete rows then they gain a rowstate of deleted and a delete query will fire when you call adapter.Update

Modify rows to cause an update to fire. Add new rows for insert

As Steve noted, you jettisoned all the rows, added new ones, added (probably uselessly) a primary key(the strongly typed table will likely have already had this key) which doesn't mean that the new rows are automatically associated to the old/doesn't cause them to be updated, hen inserted a load of new rows and wrote them to the db. This process was never going to update or delete anything

The way this is supposed to work is, you download rows, you see them in the grid, you add some, you change some, you delete some, you hit the save button. Behind the scenes the grid just poked some new rows into the datatable, marked some as deleted, changed others. It didn't go to the huge (and unfortunately incorrect) lengths your code went to. If you want your code to behave the same you follow the same idea:

```
var pta = new PersonTableAdapter();
var pdt = pta.GetData(); //query that returns all rows
pta.Fill(somedataset.Person); //or can do this
pdt = somedataset.Person;     //alias of Person table

var p = pdt.FindByPersonId(123); //PersonId is the primary key in the datatable
p.Delete(); //mark person 123 as deleted

p = pdt.First(r => r.Name = "Joe"); //LINQ just works on strongly typed datatables, out of the box, no messing

p.Name = "John"; //modify joes name to John

pdt.AddPersonRow("Jane", 22);

pta.Update(pdt); //saves changes(delete 123, rename joe, add Jane) to db
```

What you need to appreciate is that all these commands are just finding or creating datarow obj3cts, that live inside a table.. the table tracks what you do and the adapter uses appropriate sql to send changes to the db.. if you wanted to mark all rows in a datatable as deleted you can visit each of them and call Delete() on it, then update the datatable to save the changes to the db